# Efficient text to binary conversion in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, javafx

I wrote a Java FX application that translates binary to and from String and numbers in Java. Whenever the program is translating large amounts of text to binary it takes a very long time, and leaves the application unresponsive. Could a more efficient algorithm be used to speed up the process?

```
    // Turns binary into text. 
private void binaryToText() throws BinaryFormatException
{ 
    if (input.toString().length() % 8 != 0)
        throw new BinaryFormatException("Binary must be a multiple of 8");

    String input = this.input.toString();
    String _byte = "", textResult = "";

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= input.length() ; i++) {
        _byte += input.charAt(i-1);
        if (i % 8 == 0) {
            int charCode = Integer.parseInt(_byte, 2);
            textResult += (char) charCode;
            _byte = "";
        }
    }

    this.output = textResult;
}

// Turns text into binary. 
private void textToBinary()
{
    String binResult = "";
    final String fourBitPrepend = "0000";
    final String twoBitPrepend = "00";
    final String bitPrepend = "0";
    byte[] charCodes = input.toString().getBytes();

    for(byte ch : charCodes) {
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(ch);
        switch(binary.length()) {
            case 4 : binResult += fourBitPrepend + binary; break;
            case 6 : binResult += twoBitPrepend + binary; break;
            case 7 : binResult += bitPrepend + binary; break;
            default : binResult += binary;
        }
    }

    this.output = binResult;
}
```

Comment: The algorithmic problem causing `a very long time` to be taken is not visible in the in the code presented: appending single `char`s to a `String` causes a new `StringBuilder` to be instantiated, initialised with the `String`'s contents, and extended with the `char`. Then, a new `StringBuilder` to be instantiated and initialised with the `String`'s contents - in a loop, consuming noticeable time in no time: use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder-java.lang.CharSequence-) & `append()`. (Repeated `input.toString()` doesn't help.)

Comment: (The "`String +`-issue" aside, your `binaryToText()` looks even weirder than the `textToBinary()`: please disclose the type of data member `input`. If this is an assignment in learning Java, please tell to help avoid spoiling a learning experience.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you may speed up your code execution. But the core problem remains: Inresponsive UI executing a long running task.

If you expect the user wait for completion a long running task you should consider UI supported synchronized mechanisms to adress it.

Asynchronous execution is mentioned here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

The idea is: Execute your code in a separate thread and synchronize results by publishing them through the Java FX thread.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX Nodes runs on a separate UI Thread and this Thread should never be used other than to update the UI Components..
Always use a separate Thread to do the operations not related to UI.
see [this PrimeFinder](http://pastebin.com/qNgMsAxw) Example.

And here is my version of your `binaryToText`

```
private static String binaryToText(String input) {

    if (input.length() % 8 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must be a multiple of 8");
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i+=8) {
            int charCode = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i,i+8), 2);
            result.append((char) charCode);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Make it a habit to provide a size to constructors if you got a good guess (`final byte[] textBytes = input.getBytes();
     final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(textBytes.length*8);`. (The whole idea of implementing something without a specification is fallacious - and the `binaryToText(String input)` ended up doing something dissimilar. Going "bare metal" for `textToBinary()` would eliminate leading-zero-contortions but for the funny `case 4/6/7` from the question.)

Comment: @greybeard u caught me. i just removed the code for now till i got it with proper specification